# What does בחי"ח stand for?

Tags: jewish-books, acronyms, tur

In the Bet Yosef on Siman 248 in Orah Hayim, he quotes Rabbenu Yeruham בחי"ח. What does this stand for, and where can I find it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Beit Yosef there](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x1159) is referring to חלק י״ח, [section 18](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9380&st=&pgnum=182), of Rabbeinu Yerocham's discussion of the laws of Shabbat in his Sefer Toledot Adam veChavah, Adam, Netiv 12. Thus, בחי״ח stands for בחלק י״ח.